# If you do not know what is haram how can you tell?

Tags: halal-haram

I was looking at a sweet packet for my children but I never knew what was haram and what was halal. How can i tell?

Comment: have you check the ingredients mentioned on sweet packet?

Comment: One way of telling is if it has suitable for vegetarians on it

Answer (score 3):

Assalamu alaikum
There are quite a few different additives placed in products which can be seen in the ingredients. Any ingredient derived from animal such as gelatine, some emulsifiers, and even some flavour enhancers should be researched to see where they are derived from.

For example, not all gelatine is from pork. If it says beef gelatine, you still need to call up the company to see where they get their beef from, and then call up that beef company to see if they are certified halal. Keep in mind that alot of 'halal' food products and companies aren't actually halal according to shariah, they just have the certificate which could be fake. I know alot of people wouldn't care about this and probably wouldn't go into as much detail as they should, but if you do it for the sake of Allah SWT, InShaAllah you will get rewarded for it.

Keep in mind the number codes that come with an ingredient though and do your research, InShaAllah Allah will make it easy for you to come across what is halal amen

Also bear in mind that alcohol is used in some products as preservatives, though im not sure what the code is for it

Comment: -1 for `you still need to call up the company`. Unless it says pork gelatin, you shouldn't have to call anyone, which is the Sunnah of the prophet PBUH.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim if it says pork gelatin there is no need to call up the company, as the word 'pork' is enough to know it is not halal. and plus items werent packaged with numerous types of food additives for the prophet PBUH to need to 'call the company', so how can it be sunnah? in those days you didnt need to worry if the food was halal or not, because buying meat from a muslim merchant meant the meat was most certainly halal anyway. the whole point of calling up the company is to confirm what meat was used, and if its halal or not.

Comment: I'll give you that -1 back once you make an edit to your question (can't change my vote without an edit). The prophet ate from a newly convert Muslim without asking if it was Islamically slaughtered and when the companions showed concern he said that it is OK. From that I believe that unless something is haram for sure, you should eat it without asking if it is coming from the religions of Abraham PBUH.

Comment: @AmericanMuslim fair enough, i understand where you're coming from, i too have heard something similar to that, but to clarify, the religions of Abraham PBUH would include  "ahl alkitab" which means the people of the book, as the prophet knew PBUH that those people slaughtered their meat meeting the halal conditions. in todays day and age its not like that anymore, but i definitely understand where you are coming from :) oh btw  i havent really changed my wording much in my answer but i edited it anyways, so thank you :)))

Comment: @TashannaChamma , On the whole, your answers looks nice and good. Especially, indicating the issue of gelatine can be considered as a constructive issue which nowadays plenty of people are involved.../ Well done. / vote +1 for its constructiveness/

Answer (score -3):

The ingredients are almost always on the back of the package,

Everything that contains alcohol (not medicine) or animal parts that has not been slaughtered in a Islamic way is Haram to eat.

If you cannot see it is Haram and are doubting if you should get it but can live without it then don't get it.

It's better to avoid something doubtful.

Allah knows best,

Comment: When you say `been slaughtered in a Islamic way`, can you elaborate on that. Also eating things with Alcohol depends on the ingredients as well, if you extract that Alcohol out and a bucket of it does not get you drunk it is not haram.

Comment: When we slaughter an animal, the name of Allah has to be said on it. The animal has to be killed by the neck so that it will feel no pain and all the blood can drip from the body. The name of Allah and the letting the blood drip is a MUST.  Regarding alcohol,  drinking a little bit of beer will also not get you drunk, but is it allowed? No. Because it is made as an intoxicant, even if you extract the alcohol out, it was made for consuming to get drunk and not as medicine. Alcohol is only allowed when you use it external, as medicine or as part of a meal (I cannot tell you anything about food)

Comment: To clarify one more thing, when I say alcohol it's not the sort of alcohol that you use for intoxicants (beer, wine etc). You will need to do some research on the internet, I cannot tell you more than this, my knowledge stops here on this topic.

Comment: I don't see what alcohol-based medicines have to do with the question *at all*.

Comment: -1 For the halal slaughtered by Muslims only, as stated in the Quran that meat slaughtered by Jews/Christian is also halal.

Comment: I just added the medicine part so that people know medicine is allowed if it will heal you. And yes slaughtered animals from Jews and Christians are allowed but you have to think f four your self. How many people do you know that slaughter animals when the name of God is said? Almost none, the food in the supermarket would also have been allowed but isn't. It's just slaughtered and not by shooting, injecting etc. Or by sometimes machines. This is why it's better to eat just the meat that has been slaughtered in a Islamic way to assure yourself the name of God is said